# Constructor ... is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) - but it does match

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, argument-passing

So i'm doing an assignment for school in java... It's a class hierarchy kind of assignment and we are supposed to make a "Triangle.java" class that extends a "ClosedShape.java" class which extends a "Shape.java" .... the ClosedShape and Shape are both given to us, so most likely nothing wrong with them (i'll post them anyway) but my Triangle class is as follows:

```
    public abstract class Triangle extends ClosedShape{

        public Triangle(int[] a, int[] b, int base, int height){
            super(true, 3, a, b);
            setWidth(base);
            setHeight(height);
            setXYCoords(a, b);
        }

         public Triangle(int x, int y, int base, int height){
            int[] a = new int[3];
            int[] b = new int[3];

            a[0] = x;
            a[1] = (x+base)/2;
            a[2] = (x+base);

            b[0] = y;
            b[1] = (y+height)/2;
            b[2] = (y+height);
         }

}
```

The reason I have two constructors is because i need to create those two arrays to hold the points for drawing the shape...and then I need to have them passed into the ClosedShape(boolean, int, int[], int[]) super class... if i create the arrays in the same constructor they would need to be defined before the call to super() so they could be passed in, but that's not allowed because the call to super() must be first...so currently, when I try to compile Triangle.java i get the error:

```
Triangle.java.14: error: no suitable constructor found for ClosedShape()
  { //little arrow pointing under the '{'

constructor ClosedShape.ClosedShape(boolean, int, int[], int[]) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)      
    constructor ClosedShape.ClosedShape(boolean, int) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
```

It also specifies in the assignment that the signature for the triangle **must** be Traingle(int x, int y, int base, int height)... So....i'm confused because if i'm not mistaken (which java believes i am...) I made a super call with all the proper values, and there *is* a constructor "ClosedShape(boolean, int, int[], int[])"... heres the ClosedShape class:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class ClosedShape extends Shape {
    boolean polygon;
    int numPoints;
    int[] xVertices;
    int[] yVertices;
    int x,y,width, height;

    public ClosedShape(boolean isPolygon, int numPoints) {
        super(0,0);
        this.polygon = isPolygon;
        this.numPoints = numPoints;
    }

    public ClosedShape(boolean isPolygon, int numPoints, int[] x, int[] y) {
        super(x[0],y[0]);
        this.polygon = isPolygon;
        if (isPolygon) {
            this.numPoints = numPoints;
            xVertices = new int[numPoints]; // error check?  if x.length == numPoints
            //for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { // make copy of array: why?
            //  xVertices[i] = x[i];
            //}
            yVertices = new int[numPoints]; // error check?  if y.length == numPoints
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) { // make copy of array
                    yVertices[i] = y[i];
            }
        }
        else { // its an oval - define bounding box
            this.numPoints = 4;
            this.x = x[0];
            this.y = y[0];
            width = x[1];
            height = y[1];
        }
    }

    public void setXYCoords(int[] x, int[] y){
        this.xVertices = x;
        this.yVertices = y;
    }

    // Gives access to the width attribute
    public void setWidth(int width){
        this.width = width;
    }

    // Gives access to the height attribute
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (polygon) {
            g.drawPolygon(xVertices, yVertices, numPoints);
        }
        else {
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        }

    }

    public abstract double Area();
    public abstract double Perimeter();








}
```

Comment: My advice?  Believe the compiler.  Your code is wrong.

Comment: Changing the second constructor to public void Triangle(...) makes it no longer a constuctor. It now becomes an ordinary method on Triangle. Thus, it now compiles because you changed your problematic constructor to not be a constructor.

Comment: That's crazy advice.  If you need a constructor, write it properly.

Comment: I needed a constructor, I made one, but didn't realize that by ommiting the void from the second method, java would recognize it as a constructor, not a method, which is what I needed it to be. Novice mistake. :) (Which I am by the way... huge novice...lol)

Comment: I reverted back to my original code, I understand that both the methods are constructors which they cant be in this case...so how else could i get those arrays into the *super()* call...?

Comment: I realized by doing what I did... it voids the specifications of making the constructor *(int x, int y, int base, int height)* format... hmm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I'm making a call to a constructor that I don't even need to use! I only need to make a call to the first constructor then use `setXYCoords()` method to do what i need to do with the arrays.... heres my final code:

(ClosedShape.java stayed the same)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Triangle extends ClosedShape{

    public Triangle(int x, int y, int base, int height){
        super(true, 3);

        setWidth(base);
        setHeight(height);

        int [] arrayX = new int[3];
        arrayX[0] = x;
        arrayX[1] = (x+(width/2));
        arrayX[2] = (x+width);

        int [] arrayY = new int[3];
        arrayY[0] = y;
        arrayY[1] = (y-height);
        arrayY[2] = y;

        setXYCoords(arrayX, arrayY);

    }

    public double Area(){
                return 0;
    }

    public double Perimeter(){
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there's no default, no-arg constructor for `ClosedShape`.

Look at this ctor:

```
 public Triangle(int x, int y, int base, int height){
```

There's no explicit call to a `super()` constructor, so the compiler assumes that it needs to call the no-arg constructor.  But there isn't one...

Comment: Better check yourself, user93353.  It's the other ctor that's the issue, not the one you're looking at.

Comment: I understand what I did wrong there... I edited it and put my single change haha if i'm not mistaken it should be fine now... I hope hahaha it compiled :) thank you!

Comment: So what's the change?  Writing a no-arg constructor for ClosedShape or, better yet, adding the correct super call to Triangle?

Comment: well I made the second method into a method not a constrictor by changing the signature to **public *void* Triangle(...)**

Comment: *"well I made the second method into a method not a constrictor by changing the signature to **public void Triangle(...) "***   ...which i just realized voids the specifications of the constructor being **(int x, int y, int base, int height)** format... uh oh

Answer (score -1):

As @duffymo has stated, if you do not explicitly call `super()`, the compiler will insert a call to the no-arg constructor.

I think the solution you're looking for is a Factory Method.  You can create a static method, `createTriangle(int x, int y, int base, int height)`, for example.  Build your arrays in that method, call the appropriate constructor and then return the constructed object.

Comment: He doesn't need to use a static method or factory. He needs to look closer at the ClosedShape class.

Comment: I don't think advice from Marshmellow1328 is the best in light of the comment above.